# How to rid of comments in Primefaces embedded jquery and other JS files?

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I would like to know if it's possible to rid of comments from
jquery and othe JS files embeded in PrimeFaces project.

Here we may see that first line in embeded jquery:
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0-SNAPSHOT

is comment:

```
/*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
```

I would like to rid of it, not to give user any information about version of library

Or maybe it is possible to forbid direct access to this file, so user cannot just
access from browser ?

I'm using: GlassFish 5.0.1, PrimeFaces 7.0

Best Regards.

Comment: The MIT licence does not allow you to remove that comment from jQuery: https://jquery.org/license/ `You are free to use the Project in any other project (even commercial projects) as long as the copyright header is left intact.`

Comment: Ok, that is good reason not to remove this. But is this technically possible ?

Comment: Unlikely given that you're reading from a third party source. Also note that even if you remove the version comment people can still type `jQuery.fn.jquery` in to the console to see the version of jQuery you have loaded. As such what you're trying to do is almost entirely pointless.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that I had vulnerability scan, and there is suggestion to not expose version of library in header. So maybe the solution would be not to remove whole comment, but only jQuery v3.4.1 version information. If I do this it would be ok, even if user could type  jQuery.fn.jquery.

Comment: You could use a Faces resource handler to remove that line. Not that by removing that line it becomes impossible to know what library / version is used.